# Trying to alter/modify Windows Hosts file as administrator using Python, but getting "Permission denied"

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying to modify windows Hosts (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) file as administrator, but every time getting the same error:

> IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

```
import ctypes, subprocess,shutil ,sys

ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", sys.executable, " ".join(sys.argv), None, 1)

subprocess.call(['C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe', 'C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts'])

append = open('C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts','a').write("127.0.0.1      www.google.com")

print(append.read())
```

Comment: Why do you try to remote-control Notepad instead of (or in addition to) just modifying the file directly?

Comment: opening notepad is not an issue , just trying to access .exe files using my program.The main problem is here append = open('C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts','a').write("127.0.0.1      www.google.com")

Comment: As the error message says, you have no permission to modify that file.